# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MemoryPool'. Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core project I have the following on Startup:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

app.UseMiddleware<TokenHandler>();
```

I get the below error for few requests only:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'MemoryPool'.    at
> System.Buffers.MemoryPoolThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException(ExceptionArgument
> argument)    at System.Buffers.SlabMemoryPool.Lease()    at
> System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.AllocateSegment(Int32 sizeHint)    at
> System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.AllocateWriteHeadSynchronized(Int32 sizeHint)
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.OutputProducer.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1
> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.<>c__DisplayClass335_0.<g__WriteFirstAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream
> utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> DesktopEngine.Helper.TokenHandler.Invoke(HttpContext context) in
> C:\DesktopEngine\Helper\TokenHandler.cs:line 62    at
> DesktopEngine.MiddleWare.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) in
> C:\DesktopEngine\MiddleWare\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 26|

How to fix this?

Comment: How MemoryPool being used in your application?

Comment: No. we are not using MemoryPool in our application

Comment: can you show MiddleWare? Maybe throw error fro wrong using to InvokeMethods and another reason.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/pqRpyX  - middleware code

Comment: Can you reproduce easily? It should never happen.

Comment: No. I could not replicate the issue easily. what is the solution for the issue ?

Comment: It seems the error is not directly related to the code you shown. Like you said, it's not easy to reproduce the error, I think the issue may be caused by the StreamReader. Try change the code into `using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8)){var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); request.Body.Position = 0; return body;}`